# How to use dylib file?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am trying to install a robot simulation software called V-Rep where to remotely simulate the  robots, I need to have `remoteApi.java` and `remoteApiJava.dylib` files. I can't seem to figure out how to use the dylib file. 
the error I get when I build the project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no remoteApiJava in java.library.path
```

I tried running the dylib file directly in terminal, didn't work.

I placed it in `/projectPath/lib/`, and added it as a build path in eclipse, didn't work

I also tried setting up the environment variable in run config, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = /projectPath/lib/` didn't work either.

What did I do wrong there?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, you need to set `java.library.path` to include your dylib file.

Comment: ah that make sense, I didn't realize you need to set the path manually. I thought it was magically done in the background!

Comment: @BoristheSpider I tried that, still couldn't find the class... while eclipse was able to find other .class files in that folder, just not the .dylib file. I even tried to rename it to .jnilib, still didn't work.

Comment: so you ran your program with `java -jar myProgram.jar -Djava.library.path=path/to/remoteApiJava.dylib`?

Comment: yes i did, in fact i even put the remoteApiJava.dylib in `/Library/Java/Extensions/`, I still couldn't load the file. I tried load it directly using `System.load()` and it worked perfectly. Not sure why `System.loadLibrary()` doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever finish this?

Comment: System.load(<absolute path to dylib>) worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

To load a native library in java you can use one of these approaches:

#### Using System.load

You can use [`System.load(String filename)` function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)) to load a library directly from the file system, you must specify the absolute path name of your native library. For example `System.load("/System/libraries/libSomeNative.dylib")`.

#### Using System.loadLibrary

You can alternatively use [`System.loadLibrary(String libName)` function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)) to load a native library. This method is system dependent and require that
you specify `java.library.path` with the paths where your native library is located. In your case you can use `-Djava.library.path=/path/toNativeLib/` as a java argument.

Alternatively since you're trying with **Eclipse** you can specify also this path in the follow way: *Right click on project > Properties*. Then select *Java Build path and click on Source tab*, here if you expand your source folder you can set the *Native library location* specifying the path of your native library:

[image]

Since this call is system dependent note that `libName` parameter of the `System.loadLibrary(String libName)` is not the native library name directly. In *MAC OS X* (it works diferent on others OS) it use the `lib` prefix and the `.dylib` suffix on the `libName`, so to specify `libSomeNative.dylib` you've to use `SomeNative` as `libName`.

Summarize, for example to load `/System/libraries/libSomeNative.dylib` you've to specify `java.library.path=/System/libraries/` as explained above and make a call to `System.loadLibrary("SomeNative")`.